# Ubuntu 22.04 laptop freezes on shutdown

Tags: shutdown, freeze

I shutdown my MSI Prestige 15 with Ubuntu 22.04 on it. It is stuck at the screen that says “MSI” in the middle with Ubuntu at the bottom. I believe the three dots are supposed to be spinning to indicate activity: but they are frozen in place.

I tried alt SysRq RSEIUB. it didn’t do anything.

I am suspicious the computer is so frozen that only waiting for the battery to run out will fix it. But how do I prevent this from happening again? It’s almost an entirely new laptop: had it for less than a month. Clean install. Only Ubuntu 22.04 on it. What do I do?

Comment: It didn't fully boot yet; holding the power button *will* cause it to shut down and then you can restart it, but no guarantees that it won't break anything (most likely waiting for it to die on its own will not be any safer though)

Comment: Holding power worked, thanks. I just hadn’t held it long enough.